# SetDestination shows a different value than the one being set

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, path-finding, hololens, navmesh

I'm trying to use the dynamic path-finding API of Unity to implement an indoor-navigation like feature in using a HoloLens.

However, when I call the agent's setDestination method and observe the value of destination in the very next line, the value of agent's destination is incorrect.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is -1.3,-1.1,1.2?  Is it the previously assigned destination, or the current Agent position, or just a random seeming location?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few funny bits with Setting destination.
Calculation of the Path isn't done immediately, it can often take a few frames.

I can see that pathPending is false, but I don't think that necessarily means you have the new destination/path ready.
The docs from [pathPending](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent-pathPending.html) say:

> Is a path in the process of being computed but not yet ready? (Read
>   Only)

So maybe if the process of computing the path hasn't even begun yet, it still returns false.  And you're still looking at the previous destination?

Try waiting for [hasPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent-hasPath.html) to return true instead, and see if it helps.

You could also try just yielding for a few seconds but that's not an ideal way of doing it.

Comment: I doubt that's the case. The new path may not be ready, but at least the agent's destination should've changed. I major question revolves when I explicitly set the destination in line 43, why does it show a different destination in line 44.